# Can I write an InternetExplorer.document to another InternetExplorer window?

Tags: excel, vba, mshtml

I'd like to bring the IE.Document of one window into the IE.document of another window. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the sense behind your question. But you can do that in this way:

```
Sub DocFromIEtoIE()

Dim ieOne As Object
Dim ieTwo As Object
Dim nodeHTML As Object
Dim htmlDoc As String
Dim url As String

  url = "https://stackoverflow.com/"

  Set ieOne = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
  ieOne.Visible = True
  ieOne.navigate url
  Do Until ieOne.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

  Set nodeHTML = ieOne.document.getElementsByTagName("html")(0)
  If Not nodeHTML Is Nothing Then
    htmlDoc = nodeHTML.outerHTML

    Set ieTwo = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    ieTwo.Visible = True
    ieTwo.navigate "about:blank"
    Do Until ieTwo.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop

    ieTwo.document.Write (htmlDoc)
  End If
End Sub
```